# XSLT - Use a tag property later in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got a weird XSL file (generated from a soft named Lotus Notes), and I need to transform all the tags and values in HTML. I've done some string format like size, strong, color. But that's the easy part, because it's just a property on a font tag.

The new main problem is that the information I need is in a different tag of the tag which have the data to be tagged (I'm not sure I'm clear in my text).

You can see bellow in the code example we have a  with an "id" and later, we can find a  with the same id which means I need to apply the  property on this

Dxl file example (look at comments) :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM 'xmlschemas/domino_9_0_1.dtd'>
<document xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' version='9.0' maintenanceversion='1.9'
 replicaid='C125700D0056E05D'>
 <item name='Texte'>
  <richtext>
   <par def='92'>
    <run>
     <font size='12pt' name='serif'/>Some random texte here just to show how are used the font, run and other tags</run>
    <run>
     <font size='12pt' style='bold' name='serif'/>
     Bold text here
    </run>
    <run>
     <font size='12pt' name='serif'/>
    </run>
    <run>
     <font size='12pt' name='serif'/> and the end of the sentence not bold
    </run>
   </par>
   <par def='92'/>
   <pardef id='93' leftmargin='1.2500in' list='bullet'/> <!-- The interesting properties to apply -->
   <par def='93'> <!-- Id 93 so need to apply list -->
    <run>
     <font size='12pt' name='serif'/>
     First part which need to be in the list
    </run>
   </par>

   <par def='93'> <!-- Id 93 so need to apply list -->
    <run>
     <font size='12pt' name='serif'/>
     Second line of the list
    </run>
   </par>

   <par def='92'/> <!-- Other id so need to apply id 92 if exist -->
   <par def='92'>
    <run>
     <font size='12pt' name='serif'/> 
    </run>
   </par>
   <par def='92'/>
   ...
```

You can see in this example that I need to take the properties of  with id 93 to use it to the  with the same id. Here, create a list and a  for each  with this id.

```
<ul>
 <li>
  First part which need to be in the list
 </li>
 <li>
  Second line of the list
 </li>
</ul>
```

And these are repeated a lot of times, so I need to use it frequently for each  with properies I have in my file.

I tryed to use variables but it can't be changed, and I looked for arrays to initialize an array with all the ids and properties but I found that's not possible.

What's the correct way to achieve this kind of request ?

The template I've done for now if it can help :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dxl="http://www.lotus.com/dxl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="dxl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dxl:document" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="dxl:document">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="dxl:item/dxl:richtext" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="dxl:item/dxl:richtext">
        <div>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">                
                <xsl:call-template name="richtext.block" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- -->
    <xsl:template name="richtext.block">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name() = 'par'">
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:call-template name="richtext.inline" />
                </xsl:for-each>
                <br />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name() = 'pardef'">
                <xsl:value-of select="dxl:pardef/@align"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Richtext -->
    <xsl:template name="richtext.inline">
        <xsl:call-template name="richtext.nonhot.inline" />
        <xsl:call-template name="richtext.hot.inline" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="richtext.nonhot.inline">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name() = 'run'">
                <xsl:call-template name="richtext.design" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name() = 'urllink'">
                <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    
                    <xsl:call-template name="richtext.design" />
                </a>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="richtext.hot.inline">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="richtext.design">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="normalize-space(text()) != ''">
                <font>
                    <xsl:variable name="calculatedSize" select="dxl:font/@size"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="calculatedSize" select="substring($calculatedSize, 0, string-length($calculatedSize)-1)"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="size">
                        <xsl:value-of select="round(number($calculatedSize) div 4)" />
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:attribute name="color">
                        <xsl:value-of select="dxl:font/@color" />
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:attribute name="style">font-family: <xsl:value-of select="dxl:font/@name" />;
                        <xsl:if test="contains(dxl:font/@style, 'bold')">font-weight: bold;</xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="contains(dxl:font/@style, 'underline')">text-decoration: underline;</xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
                </font>
            </xsl:when>
            
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I hope it's clear, and someone will help me to figure it out, I'm really stucked here...

Thanks a lot of all ppl who are even just trying :)

Regards

Comment: HTML `font` element in 2021? Really? Which browsers are you producing the HTML for? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Comment: Do you have an XSLT 3 processor available, as your XSLT code using `version="3.0"` suggests? What are the exact rules, are all adjacent `par def` elements to be merged or even `par def` with the same id which have other siblings in between?

Comment: @MartinHonnen The first part is generated by a tool, but that's not the HTML I'm gonna create. I will transform it into css style if I can, I have no choice to start from this kind of file with old tags...

I don't know the answer for the XSLT 3 processor, I'm using in my test a nodeJS mini program with xslt3 library so I guess I can yes.

The `pardef` are always specified before the `par` using it, but after a `pardef`, a `par` can reference the id of a previous one. I'm not sure that answer your question.